# Defer loading in JavaScript, Jquery 'ready()' runs before JQuery is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred-loading

I am loading two JS files, one with many plugins, including Jquery. The 'ready()' JQuery function is in the second file.

Code:

```
   function downloadJSAtOnload() {

       var element = document.createElement("script");
       element.src ='<%= deferJsAll %>';
       document.body.appendChild(element);

      // second JS file load with isReady goes here
   }

   // Check for browser support of event handling capability
   if (window.addEventListener)
       window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
   else if (window.attachEvent)
       window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
   else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
```

You can see when I also load the second file (See comment inside the code).

The problem is that I can't control the order of execution and even so, the 'ready()' runs before JQuery is loaded, and I get an error. Is there an option to use defer loading and making sure that the Jquery files loads first and then the second is executed (the one with the ready() function)?

I am using "<%= deferJsAll %>" because I am deciding which file to serve from CDN, the gzip or plain text JS file.

Progress: I thought about just putting:

```
var elementApp = document.createElement("script");
elementApp.src = 'js/app.js';
document.body.appendChild(elementApp);
```

at the end of the first document. So when the first document finishes loading, it will then embed the second dependent JS code into the body of the document. Do you think it's a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution I used when I need to wait until some var on the page exists. It takes a name (e.g. `jQuery` or namespace `twttr.widgets` with arbitrary depth) and other self explanatory attributes. Works in production on http://www.vitalmtb.com/ when I need to wait till Facebook and Twitter widgets are loaded.

```
// Wait till JS object is loaded. It can be a chanined variable name.
window.whenAvailable = function (name, callback, interval, max_wait) {
    interval || (interval = 50); // ms
    max_wait || (max_wait = 5000); // ms
    var timer,
        findVarByName = function(name) {
        var index = 0,
            parts = name.split('.'),
            result = window;

        index = 0;
        try {
            while (typeof result !== "undefined" && result !== null && index < parts.length) {
                result = result[parts[index++]];
            }
        }
        catch (e) {}
        if (index < parts.length || (typeof result == 'undefined' && result === undefined)) return false;
        else return true;
    };

    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (findVarByName(name)) {
            return callback();
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
        }
    }, interval);

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }, max_wait);
}
```

Use:

```
whenAvailable('FB', $j.spotlights.a.show_social_buttons);
whenAvailable('twttr.widgets', $j.spotlights.b.show_social_buttons);
```

Comment: While i'm sure this solution is great when you don't have proper callbacks for when something is loaded. It's kind of a "brute force" method that isn't really necessary in the OP's example code. Because _he's_ controlling when and what is loaded (vs. crazy & buggy social media crap), we can use the browser's built in methods such as onload.

Comment: Well but you can use `$(document).ready(...)` as a callback.
Otherwise, I advise to use Require.js.

Comment: +1 for requireJS. If you're getting to the point where you're loading more than one file asynchronously, then I think require is the way to go. As far as $doc.ready goes, I'm not sure that applies here. The thing is $doc.ready is for detecting when the DOM is complete, not when jQuery is ready. You can't call that before jQuery exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use onload & onreadystatechange (for IE) to detect when the script is finished loading.

```
function loadScript(callback){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = '<%= deferJsAll %>';
  document.body.appendChild(script);

  // exit on jQuery load.
  script.onload = function(){ callback(); };
  script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 'complete') callback();
  }
}


loadScript(function(){
  $.getScript('<% jquery-dependent.js %>', function(){
     // jquery-dependent.js is loaded
  }
});
```

Comment: what about putting: var elementApp = document.createElement("script");
elementApp.src = 'js/second_file.js';
document.body.appendChild(elementApp);

Comment: Then you run into the same problem you were at before, which is that you can't control execution order easily in the browser. The problem is that elementApp can come back before jQuery, at which point the browser will execute it. The browser always runs scripts the moment they return.

Comment: To clarify, you can _detect_ when a script comes back, but you can't control what the browser does with it.